# How to update to the newest phpMyadmin in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

How to update from phpmyadmin 4.0.10deb1 to the newest version? i have tryed update and upgrade. is there some migrate command that does this? Im using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install phpmyadmin -y
```

I've upgraded only phpmyadmin because the repository upgrades and its' dependencies.